# question about swap bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

i have question on this topic i  think that  answer is incorrect look

[Swap bits in a number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192487/swap-bits-in-a-number-in-c)

1110 1011 it is equal 235 but i get 3051  why?

Comment: Are you using an 8-bit unsigned char?  You must not be since you are getting 3051 as your answer.  As mentioned in the comment the code is only going to work on an 8 bit data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `3051` in decimal is `101111101011` in binary. If you split it up into four bit segmens like this: `1011 1110 1011`, you see that the lowest four bits are repeated above the eight bits that you want. The reason for that is that you haven't masked the value that should be the top four bits.

So instead of something like this:

```
(c >> 4) | ((c & 0x0f) << 4)
```

or something like this:

```
((c >> 4) | (c << 4)) & 0xff
```

you simply have this:

```
(c >> 4) | (c << 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you *do* have the correct number, but you are using `%d` to print it without *casting* it to an int (or something else funny in the way you display it).

I say this because `(3051 & 235) == 235`, which is an unlikely coincidence to happen randomly.

Comment: Casting to `int` won't do any good -- 3051 will fit into an `int`. To do any good, you'd need to cast to `unsigned char` (and that's suspect -- code that produces 3051 where 235 is intended clearly needs to be fixed, not fudged around, at least IMO).

Answer (score 0):

You've shown only 8 bits, which means the maximum possible value is 2<sup>8</sup>-1, which works out to 255.

3051 in binary is: 1011 1110 1011, so to get that, you've apparently duplicated the least significant nybble into the third nybble.